# rxjava testScheduler race condition

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java3

I stumbled upon a weird testScheduler behavior that I cannot wrap my head around. The code below is greatly simplified, but it origins in a real life issue.

Consider this test:

```
@Test
fun testSchedulerFun(){

    val testScheduler = TestScheduler()

    val stringsProcessor = PublishProcessor.create<String>()

    val completable = Completable.complete()

    completable
        .doOnComplete { stringsProcessor.onNext("onComplete") }
        .subscribeOn(testScheduler)
        .subscribe()

    val testSubscriber = stringsProcessor
        .subscribeOn(testScheduler) //this line of code messes the test
        .test()

    testScheduler.triggerActions()

    testSubscriber
        .assertValues("onComplete")

}
```

**When I subscribe the tested `stringsProcessor` on `testScheduler`, the test fails. When I remove that line it succeeds. **

The flow of events as I see it is:

1. triggerActions
2. completable and stringsProcessor are being subscribed and propagate their events downstream.
3. And apparently the `stringsProcessor.onNext("onComplete")` is evaluated **after** the testSubscriber has finished.

**I want to know why**

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace related to the failing case?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari The stack trace is just that assertion fails, i.e. there is no value present in testSubscriber.

Comment: Can you add completable.observeOn(testScheduler) in the failing test?

Comment: @SaeedEntezari it passes. Interesting. Do you know why? Side note: I also added something to the processor in doOnSubscribe and that doesn't pass, just what is there in doOnComplete.

Comment: I guess it is a race condition. You are calling all the functions here on the main thread in a non blocking way. So when it reaches the end (assert statement), the testScheduler did not yet finish the process to emit a value thus no value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the test fails is because `stringProcessor` has no subscriber the time you call `onNext` on it. That subscriber only comes after because you added the "this line messes up" `subscribeOn`.

There is no race condition involved because everything runs on the same thread in a deterministic order:

1. when the code executes `completable ... subscribe()` part, a task is queued with `testScheduler` that will perform the doOnComplete call.
2. when the code executes the `test` part, another task is queued with `testScheduler` that will observe the processor.
3. triggerActions executes task 1, which emits the value to no subscribers, then executes task 2 and now ready to observe the processor, but nothing comes.